# Can I replace a MBP 2012 SSD with the Flash storage from a MBP 2013?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, flash-memory

My son's MBP (13-inch, Mid 2012) internal SSD has been acting strangely enough that I'm starting to wonder if it needs to be replaced (do SSDs fail?). I have a MBP (retina 15-inch, Early 2013) with a failing logic/graphics board combo that I'm going to need to replace anyway.

Can I take the 512 GB flash storage from my 2013 MBP and put it into my son's machine? I realize that the process may be arduous, I just wanted to find out if it's even compatible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, definable you not.  The 2013 MacBook Pro laptops use a proprietary PCIe interface whereas the 2012 used a SATA III interface.

There *may* be a PCIe to SATA adapter, but I haven seen any that are compatible with the Mac’s proprietary interface.  Even so, SATA SSDs are very cost effective right now, so it’s not practical to add that extra layer of complexity by putting an adapter into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

mbp 2012: sata interface.
mbp early 2013: also sata interface, so switch is easy.
mbp late 2013 PCLE interface, thus impossible to switch, and then:
Price of a sata SSD 500GB lower that 100$, so buy a new one, format the new SSD and then clone the old 2012 disk to the new SSD while it is still outside, then the switch the SSDs could be easy.